# Pegar valor da String (.net core para JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, string, value

Estou desenvolvendo um site com .net core e estou utilizando o JQuery. Na pagina `Index.cshtml.cs` eu tenho uma função que tem as validações e la me passam as mensagens (se está ok, se houve algum erro), atraves de uma string. Me ajudem, pois sou novo em .Net e eu nao tenho ideia de como fazer.

Eu preciso, no JQuery, pegar o valor desta string para eu retornar a mensagem tratada.

Agradeço a vcs.

Codigo:

```
public async Task OnPostAsync(parametros)
{
    ....
    await AtivacaoVerificarAsync2(Parametros);

   //*Pegar o valor da mensagem aqui*

    return;
}

public async Task AtivacaoVerificarAsync2(Parametros)
{
     Mensagem = "deu certo";
     return;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#numeroSerie").focus();

    $("#form-login").on("submit", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://localhost:44390/",
            data: {},
            complete: function (xhr, statusText) {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    alert(myValue);//*ALERTAR A MENSAGEM AQUI*
                } else {
                    alert(myValue);//*ALERTAR A MENSAGEM AQUI*
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Não consigo usar o ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript, pois da erro no ScriptManager, dizendo que ele nao existe no contexto atual, e alem disso nao consigo tambem usar o System.Web.UI

Comment: Para pegar um valor de um **`input`** com jQuery é só fazer **$("id_ou_classe_ou_input[name='seuInput']").val()**

Comment: mas nao é o valor de um input, que eu preciso... preciso do valor de uma string que esta dentro de um metodo

Comment: Sem código disponível, não tem como saber.

Comment: adicionei um codigo base pra vc ter uma noção aí, se puder me ajudar eu agradeço

Comment: Quando você acessa o https://localhost:44390/, oque ele retorna?

Comment: ele retorna a minha pagina index, normal

Comment: Seu projeto é ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?

Comment: @Rafael sim, ele é

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, você pode alterar a action para retornar o que precisa, provavelmente o AntiforeryToken() também será um problema já que ele é ligado como default e suas chamadas retornarão erro 400. Se você não utilizar os recursos do Razor Pages talvez seja interessante usar o ASP.NET Core MVC, seria legal também atualizar e melhorar suas chamadas ajax.

Ex.:

Script: (Index.cshtml)

```
    @page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>

<form id="form-login">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input id="NumeroSerie" type="text" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

@section scripts{
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#NumeroSerie").focus();

            $("#form-login").on("submit", function (evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: { NumeroSerie: $("#NumeroSerie").val() },
                    headers: {
                        RequestVerificationToken:
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                    }

                })
                    .done(function (msg) {
                        alert(msg);
                    })
                    .fail(function (msg) {
                        alert("Erro " + JSON.stringify( msg));
                    });
            });
        });

    </script>

}
```

E na model:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApplication4.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public string NumeroSerie { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }


        public Task<JsonResult> OnPostAsync() {
            var result = ValidaAlgo();
            return Task.Run(()=> new JsonResult(result));
        }

        private string ValidaAlgo()
        {
            return NumeroSerie;
        }
    }
}
```